# Use slash commands in Slack with Bot Framework?

Tags: telegram-bot, botframework, slack-api, skype-bots

I'm just getting started with the Bot Framework and can't find any reference to supporting slash commands with it? Is this supported for Slack and other clients?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "it depends".

The Slack's [slash command API](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) is completely separate to the Bot API. You can add an additional api controller and trigger bot conversations from that API. You'll need to connect Slack directly to your bot, not via the Microsoft's middleware. This is actually the same as [what you'll do](https://beepboophq.com/docs/article/recipe-slack-slash-command-botkit) with Slack's native BotKit.

In [telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands) you can register a custom command using the [@BotFather](https://telegram.me/botfather)'s `/setcommands` command. After you've registered a custom command the telegramm will show you the select box as soon as you type `/` in a chat. When you'll invoke a "command" it will be passed to a bot as a regular text message, and you can start the conversation from that point.

For the channels, where the slash commands do exist, but are not extendable (Skype for ex., or in Slack), you can use fake commands by using a space (`" /hello"`) or dot (`"./hello"`) symbols before the slash, and handle these messages as commands.